# Bootstrap form input field that requires at least one element to be selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have form where I would like to create input field(s) for account type. This is little tricky since there might be only one account type but can be two as well. In other words when first, last name is entered then they have to choose either User or Staff for account type or they can pick both. Once they select either or both then additional fields will show int he form. My question is what is the best option to approach that would require user to select at least one account type but at the same time allow them to choose two as well if they need to? Also I use HTML5 validation for this purpose, so if they choose only one the other gonna be hidden. Those hidden form fields should not be required but now I don't have a way to prevent that. Here is example:

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_firstname" id="frm_firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_lastname" id="frm_lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account">User Account</button>
  </div>
  <div id="user-account" class="collapse">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_username" id="frm_username" placeholder="Enter UserName" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account">Staff Account</button>
  </div>
  <div id="staff-account" class="collapse">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_position" id="frm_position" placeholder="Choose Position" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="frmSaveaccount_submit" id="frmSaveaccount_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So buttons for User and Staff account are actually separate fields in my database and I have to save values for example 1 or 0 if they have entered User information or Staff. Also if I try to submit the form with only Staff information for example I can't since User form fields are hidden but still required. How that can be fixed so only visible fields are required?

Comment: If you don't mind a suggestion, maybe you should change the User/ Staff buttons for checkboxes. Then you could use some JS magic to detect when the user has selected at least one of the options and then display the related fields accordingly.

Comment: @cabrerahector The only reason why I do not like radio buttons is that you can't un-check the option.

Comment: Yep, I edited my previous comment but it seems I wasn't fast enough :P Checkboxes would do the trick though.

Comment: Also, since you want the user to pick at least account type you'll necessarily need to do the validation via JS (or at least change the HTML5 validation of every field, switching from required to optional according to the selections made, also via JS).